# Rails check_box data not saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, devise

I have a form with a `check_box` method, and when I submit the form, it doesn't save to the user.(I check using User.all in the console) It's a separate form than the sign up form, and I dont know if this is necessary, but Im using devise.

EDIT heres the console :

```
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"LPplw/AwLhpDNt4xz7+VUAFr2BefWNapVDn3w4sroUg6jPUSK1kG9Pv3+cepeY2Qw50aivhmU/HNkdKnwK1l0Q==", "user"=>{"html5"=>"1", "css3"=>"1", "ruby"=>"1", "python"=>"1", "javscript"=>"0", "jquery"=>"0", "php"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Submit"}
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Rendered dashboard/index.html.erb within layouts/application (5.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 153ms (Views: 152.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.1ms)
```

EDIT heres the form :

```
    <%=form_for (:user) do |f| %>
    <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-2">
        <%= f.check_box :html5%> <%= f.label :html5, "Html 5" %>
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-2">
        <%= f.check_box :css3%> <%= f.label :css3, "CSS 3" %>
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-2">
        <%= f.check_box :ruby%> <%= f.label :ruby %>
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-2">
        <%= f.check_box :python%> <%= f.label :python %>
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-2">
        <%= f.check_box :javscript%> <%= f.label :javascript %>
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-2">
        <%= f.check_box :jquery%> <%= f.label :jquery, "jQuery" %>
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-2">
        <%= f.check_box :php%> <%= f.label :php, "PHP" %>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-2">
        <%= f.submit "Submit", class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
    </div>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: What does the Rails logs say for the `create` or `update` action, what is the code you've got for the form, and what's the code in your `create` or `update` method in the controller?

Comment: I dont have either of those...

Comment: What code does your controller have then?

Comment: Nothing so far, just created the project. Anything it should have?

Comment: Oh wait - you're using Devise. My bad. But can you show what is in your Rails logs when you try to submit the form?

Comment: But then when I check the console, it says that the values are false

Comment: It's easier to read that if you put it in the question, not in the comments.

Comment: sorry, edited the question

Comment: I think you have not redirected the form to the create action, bcoz there is no insert query in your rails log/console.

Comment: @Sravan how would I do this??

Comment: Add the form to your question

Comment: @Sravan ok, what do I do now?

Comment: You have no action in your parameters, chanage the form to     `<%=form_for @user do |f| %>`